# Max number of users can a broadcast message target?

Tags: broadcast, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm contributing in developing a messenger bot to provide weather and alerts. One feature will consist of sending a notification to subscribers using the broadcast api of the messenger platform. Currently the Facebook page has more than 500 000 subscribers. I need to know the max number of users a broadcast message can reach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum, but if you send a broadcast of that size you need to be careful that you are sending content of actual value. If a lot of users report or block, your bot can be disabled.